# Perl: extract string between last slash and last dot (optional)

Tags: regex, perl

My strings are

`my $str1 = "/user/admin/music/dangerous-women.1";` (with number as extension)

`my $str2 = "/user/admin/music/dangerous-women";` (without number as extension)

`my $str3 = "/user/admin/music/dangerous.women.2";` (with number as extension)

How can I use regular expression to extract `dangerous-women` and `dangerous.women`

i.e. Anything between the last slash and last dot (optional).
So the extension is only number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's tricky do in a single match, so I wouldn't do it that way.

```
my $base = $str =~ s{.*/}{}sr =~ s{\.\d+\z}{}r;   # 5.14+
```

If you want to support earlier versions of Perl, you can use

```
my $base = $str;
$base =~ s{.*/}{}s;
$base =~ s{\.\d+\z}{};
```

Comment: I updated the question. Sorry for the confusion. The extension can only be a number.

Comment: Doesn't affect the answer.

Comment: It works awesome. I have spent the entire afternoon to match it. I don't realize I can use replace. I am just new to perl and regex. You alway gave me quick responds and always help me a lot. 10000000+ Thanks. @ikegami

Comment: so you replaced the part before last slash(included) with {} by using the first pattern. And the replaced `.num` with {} by using the second pattern right? @ikegami

Comment: Replaced the chars up to including the last `/` with an empty string, then replaced `.`+(1 or more digits)+EOS with an empty string.